# Какая область математики изучает сложность алгоритмов?

Tags: алгоритм

Бывает встречаются записи типо сложность алгоритмов такая-то пример(O(n²)). Подскажите пожалуйста какая область математики занимается изучением этого и литературу по этой теме.

Comment: [Первое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Быстрые_алгоритмы), что нашел.

Comment: @Александр [Не отправляйте спрашивающих в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)

Answer (score 3):

Наука называется "Теория алгоритмов". Про Кормена уже писали.

Answer (score 2):

учебник Т. Кормен - "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ" довольно сложен для чтения. Я рекомендую для начала почитать "Algorithms unlocked", автор тот же - Т. Кормен. Там реально все разжевано. После этого уже можно приступать к "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"

Answer (score 1):

Т. Кормен - Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ, 2005.  Всю читать не обязательно, но там где-то с 50 ст идут пару нужных разделов. =)